# Books: DNA replication

Tags: molecular-biology, molecular-genetics, book-recommendation

In what books can I find a detailed literature on the mechanism of function of different enzymes and proteins involved in DNA replication of *E. coli* ?

Comment: Please have a look at the [tag-wiki for book-recommendation](http://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/book-recommendation/info). You have to provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

Check this online book on NCBI: [An Introduction to Genetic Analysis. 7th edition](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21862/)

> Let’s examine each of these components and see how they fit together to produce our current picture of DNA synthesis in *E. coli*, the best-studied cellular replication system

I used it a bunch while studying *E. coli* for my master degree, lots of really usefull information.

Comment: it is Griffith et al. Also available pdf in http://www.bio.bg.ac.rs/materijali_predmeta/med-eng-griffiths-an-introduction-to-genetic-analysis.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Here's just the right book - **Lehninger Principles of Biochemistry, 6th Ed** 
By David L. Nelson, Michael M. Cox.

A Google.book [link](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=_GUdBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA1020&lpg=PA1020&dq=DUE%20dnaB&source=bl&ots=Pp8CI0sbDw&sig=IWjSAj-HNwCIZumfl-uWWR5OzDY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtq_nL3OTPAhVirVQKHZpMC40Q6AEIPjAG#v=onepage&q=DUE%20dnaB&f=false) to it.

Answer (score 1):

Molecular Biology of the Gene 
(James D. Watson
Cold Spring Harbor
Laboratory
Tania A. Baker
Massachusetts Institute
of Technology
Stephen P. Bell
Massachusetts Institute
of Technology
Alexander Gann
Cold Spring Harbor
Laboratory Press•
Michael Levine
University of California,
Berkeley
Richard Losick
Harvard University) has a detailed description of the various processes involving genetic material.
Find a pdf file here: http://tocs.ub.uni-mainz.de/pdfs/118526545.pdf

Answer (score 0):

**Biochemical Pathways** (*G. Michal, D. Schomburg*) has nice old-school schematics such as this [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZTWA.jpg), in addition to the text.